# Count not increasing on click of the button

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am building a BMI calculator app that calculator where there 2 button for selecting Male or female .There is a slider of setting the height.In the last row i have a Weight and Age container .In those  containers i have a plus button for incrementing and minus button for decrementing .
The design is shown as follows [BMI Calculator app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFzNf.png).

when i click the plus sign or Minus sign below 'Weight' and 'Age' containers the height and weight is not getting updated can u help me in figuring it out :).Thanks in advance

My code is as follows
Main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'input_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(BMICalculator());

class BMICalculator extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme:ThemeData(
        primaryColor:Color(0xFF0A0E21),//background color for major parts of the app like appbar toolbar
        accentColor: Colors.purple, //foreground color for the widgets like button
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
      ),
      home: InputPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Input_page.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:bmi_calculator/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'icon_content.dart';
import 'reusable_Card.dart';
import 'constants.dart';
class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}
enum Gender{
  male,female,
}
class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  Color maleCardColor =inactiveCardColor;
  Color femaleCardColor = inactiveCardColor;
  String gender;
  Gender selectedGender;
  int height=180;
  int weight = 60;
  int age = 20;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('BMI CALCULATOR'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children:<Widget> [
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children:<Widget> [
                Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    onPress: (){
                      setState(() {
                        selectedGender = Gender.male;//selectedGender of type enum Gender should be changed to male on clicking male button
                      });
                    },
                    colour: selectedGender ==Gender.male? kActiveCardColour:inactiveCardColor,//if color is inactive make it active if clicked  else make it inactive color
                    cardChild: IconContent(
                        icon:FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                        label:'MALE'),
                    ),
                  ),
                Expanded
                (
                child: ReusableCard(
                  onPress: (){
                    setState(() {
                      selectedGender = Gender.female;//selectedGender of type enum Gender should be changed to Female on clicking male button
                    });
                  },
                colour:selectedGender == Gender.female?kActiveCardColour:inactiveCardColor,//if color is inactive make it active if clicked  else make it inactive color
                  cardChild:IconContent(icon:FontAwesomeIcons.venus,label:'FEMALE'),
                ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child:ReusableCard(
              colour: kActiveCardColour,
              cardChild: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children:<Widget>[
                    Center(
                      child: Text('HEIGHT',
                        style: kLabelTextStyle,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,//it will not work unless u hv a text baseline property
                      textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                      children:<Widget> [
                        Text(
                          height.toString(),
                          style: kNumberTextStyle,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'cm',
                          style:kLabelTextStyle,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SliderTheme(
                      data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                        activeTrackColor: Colors.white,//active slider color
                        inactiveTrackColor: Color(0xFF8D8E98),//inactive slider color
                        thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 15),
                        thumbColor: Color(0xFFEB1555),
                        overlayColor: Color(0x15EB1555),//outline shade when the thumb is selected .This will be pink
                        overlayShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 30.0),
                      ),
                        child:Slider(
                            value: height.toDouble(),//to convert height to double
                            min: 0.0,
                            max:220.0, //active color of slider
                            onChanged: (double newValue){
                              setState(() {
                                height=newValue.round();//we update height value to the value changed according to the state
                              });
                            }
                        )
                    ),
                  ]
              ),
          ),
            ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children:<Widget> [
                Expanded(
                  child:ReusableCard(
                    colour: kActiveCardColour,
                    cardChild: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children:<Widget>[
                        Text('WEIGHT',
                        style:kLabelTextStyle,
                        ),
                        Text(weight.toString(),
                        style:kNumberTextStyle,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [

                            RoundIconButton(icon:FontAwesomeIcons.minus,
                          onPressed: (){
                              setState(() {
                                weight--;
                              });
                          },
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width:10),
                            RoundIconButton(
                              icon:FontAwesomeIcons.plus,
                              onPressed: (){
                                setState(() {
                                  weight++;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child:ReusableCard(
                    colour:kActiveCardColour,
                    cardChild: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text('Age',
                        style:kLabelTextStyle,
                        ),
                        Text(age.toString(),
                          style:kNumberTextStyle,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children:<Widget>[
                          RoundIconButton(icon: FontAwesomeIcons.minus,
                              onPressed: (){
                            setState(() {
                              age--;
                            });
                          }),
                            SizedBox(width:10),
                     RoundIconButton(
                      icon:FontAwesomeIcons.plus,
                      onPressed: (){
                        setState(() {
                          weight++;
                        });
                      },
                          ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
              Container(
            color:botttomContainerColor,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                height:kBottomContainerHeight,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
class RoundIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  RoundIconButton({@required this.icon,@required this.onPressed});//tells the user that while using the roundButton this 2 widgets r compulsory

  final IconData icon;
  final Function onPressed;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawMaterialButton(//Most basic button u can change its shape sixe stc
      elevation: 6,
      child: Icon(icon,
      color: Colors.white,),
      onPressed: (){
        onPressed;
      },
      constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(//for writing the constraints for RawMaterialButton
        width:56.0,
        height:56.0,
      ),
      shape:CircleBorder(),
      fillColor:  Color(0xFF4C4F5E),
    );
  }
}
```

Constants.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
Color maleCardColor =inactiveCardColor;
Color femaleCardColor = inactiveCardColor;
const kBottomContainerHeight =80.0;
const kActiveCardColour= Color(0xFF1D1E33);
const botttomContainerColor = Color(0xFFEB1555);
const inactiveCardColor = Color(0xFF111328);
const kNumberTextStyle = TextStyle(
  fontSize: 50,
  fontWeight:FontWeight.w900,
  color: Colors.white,
);
const kLabelTextStyle =
TextStyle(
  fontSize: 18,
  color:Color(0xFF8D8E98),
);
```

reusable_Card.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {

  ReusableCard({this.colour, this.cardChild, this.onPress});//on creating reusable cardchild we require to pass it here
  final Color colour;
  final Widget cardChild;
  final Function onPress;//OnPressed function
  //final Widget cardChild;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(//create a Gesture Detector here
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container
        (
        child:cardChild,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: colour,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

icon_content.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'constants.dart';


class IconContent extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final String label;
  IconContent({this.icon,this.label});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children:<Widget>[
          Icon(
            icon,//Instead of hardcoding the fontawesome.mars here we hv passed an icon which contains the same by calling a constructor
            color: Colors.white,
            size:80.0,
          ),
          SizedBox(height:15.0),
          Text(label,
    style:kLabelTextStyle,
            ),
        ]
          );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your on press correctly in `RoundIconButton`:

```
class RoundIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  RoundIconButton({@required this.icon,@required this.onPressed});//tells the user that while using the roundButton this 2 widgets r compulsory

  final IconData icon;
  final Function onPressed;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawMaterialButton(//Most basic button u can change its shape sixe stc
      elevation: 6,
      child: Icon(icon,
      color: Colors.white,),
      onPressed: (){
        onPressed;
      },
      constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(//for writing the constraints for RawMaterialButton
        width:56.0,
        height:56.0,
      ),
      shape:CircleBorder(),
      fillColor:  Color(0xFF4C4F5E),
    );
  }
}
```

Replace your on press like this:

```
onPressed: (){
        onPressed();
      },
```

or like this:

```
onPressed: onPressed,
```

Comment: OnPressed is also  a function of Round Icon Button..So i have called it that way

Comment: It should be onPressed(); not onPressed;